# Passing wrapper class object list to child component from parent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-attribute

I am trying to pass an attribute from parent component to child component. But the catch is this attribute is populated in apex controller using wrapper class. So currently it is a list of wrapper object. But when I am trying to pass this attribute to child component, on console log of child client controller it is showing undefined.

**Parent Apex Class:**

```
public static List<dataWrapper> getParentDetails(String RecordId){
        list<dataWrapper> lstwrpParent = new List<dataWrapper>();
//doing some query and adding to the list
return lstwrpParent 
}

public class dataWrapper{
        @auraEnabled
        public Id childRecordId{get;set;}
        @auraEnabled
        public String childName{get;set;}
        @auraEnabled
        public String recordTypeName{get;set;}
        
        public dataWrapper(Id childRecordId,String childName,String recordTypeName){
            this.childRecordId=childRecordId;
            this.childName=childName;
            this.recordTypeName=recordTypeName;
        }
    }
```

**Parent Controller:**

```
// setting the lstwrpParent response from apex class to v.parentrecordlist
```

**Parent Component:**

```
<aura:attribute name="parentrecordlist" type="Object"/>
<lightning:card title="">
      <c:ChildComponent parentData="{!parentrecordlist}" />
    </lightning:card>
```

**Child Component:**

```
<aura:attribute name="parentData" type="Object"/>
```

**Child js Controller:**

```
var test1= component.get("v.parentData");
console.log("parentData "+ test1 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure check in Server call response your getting the response or not there, and then
like on Success of your server call
add this line before assigning  to `"parentrecordlist"` variable.

```
if(state === "SUCCESS"){
 console.log('data:',response.getReturnValue());// check if here data coming
 component.set("v.parentrecordlist",response.getReturnValue());
}
```

then Change the attribute from type:

```
<aura:attribute name="parentData" type="Object"/>
```

To

```
<aura:attribute name="parentData" type="yourclassName.dataWrapper[]" />
```

Comment: yes, server call is returning values. checked using   console.log("parent " + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
Even replacing type to list is showing undefined in child js controller console log

Comment: we are good there, did you try changing the attribute type?

Comment: yes changed the attribute type to list from object still undefined.

Comment: i have updated my answer check now!

Comment: tried your yourclassName.dataWrapper[] approach but still undefined. made changes in both parent and child component aura attribute type

Comment: ur approach should have worked logically. when I am doing aura:iterate on this attribute it is displaying values correctly.

Comment: Can you try with the Aura events or Aura methods to send data to Child Component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117367/discussion-between-akash-and-umesh-beti).